# Sending push notification to specific device knowing phone number, parse.com

Tags: javascript, ios, parse-platform, subquery

I would just to get things clear here or get other suggestions if possible if it is better.

This is how my application works now:

1) Anonymous user is created if its the first time the user open the application

2) Phone verification is needed to be done. If verified, i save the phone number in a custom field in user object ( do i need to make this user a real user after this or can i still go with anonymous user?)( verification is one time only of course)

3) The user will be able to pick a friend from his contact list(ABPeoplePicker) and then send a push notification to that friend's device.

Now i have set up a relationship with the User and the installation object with this code:

```
PFInstallation *installation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
installation[@"user"] = [PFUser currentUser];
[installation saveInBackground];
```

And this created a pointer to the users ObjectId

So my question is how would i create a query and send a push notification to a number retrieved from that Users friend list?. I am having a hard time to connect how i can get from a phone number to the installation device that i need to send the notification to. If you could provide help in javascript since i read it is safer to send it through cloud code!

Also a subquestion mentioned above if i need to make the anonymous user to a real user.

many thanks!!

Comment: So the friend doesn't have your app installed, correct?

Comment: (The friend would have to have your app installed to receive the push notification.)

Comment: The friend does have the application, If he didint then he would not exist in my database in parse.com @Ramsel

Comment: @LyndseyScott maybe you will have a clue of what is going on here? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28058127/is-parse-com-push-service-really-reliable-or-am-i-doing-something-wrong?noredirect=1#comment44497999_28058127

Comment: would love to get your opinion here since you have experience with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28079184/the-verification-procedure-and-making-new-users-logic-parse-com @LyndseyScott

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend subscribing each user to their own channel where the channel name is equal to their phone number (Subscription can't be done in Javascript):

```
NSString *userPhoneNumber = ... 

PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
// "x" added to the beginning of the userPhoneNumber since
// Parse doesn't allow channels to begin with a number
[currentInstallation addUniqueObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"x%@", userPhoneNumber] forKey:@"channels"];
[currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

That way no query is required before pushing the notification:

```
var friendPhoneNumber = ...
var friendChannel = "x" + friendPhoneNumber;
Parse.Push.send({
  channels: [ friendChannel ],
  data: {
    alert: message
  }
}, {
  success: function() {
    // Push was successful
  },
  error: function(error) {
    // Handle error
  }
});
```

Comment: Wow...
Thats actually really smart never though about it. That would mean that i would not need to associate the user object to the installation object. Thank you so much...

What about the other subquestion. Do i need to make the anonymous user to a real user or should i keep it that way? @Lyndsey Scott

Comment: @TimoCengiz If you want the user info to persist after logout, you're going to need to make the anonymous user a real user. From the docs: "An anonymous user is a user that can be created without a username and password but still has all of the same capabilities as any other PFUser. After logging out, an anonymous user is abandoned, and its data is no longer accessible." https://parse.com/docs/ios_guide#users-anonymous/iOS

Comment: But how come i can still see the anonymous user in the Data/Users database after shutting the application down? Or does shutting the application down not count as "logging out"

Comment: It doesn't count as "logging out". You have to call `logOut` to log the user out... I guess technically you could keep the user as an anonymous user (and thus avoid having the user login properly) as long as you don't log out.

Comment: Hmm but that is not a preferred way right? Better to do it properly just in case?

Comment: Also i am a little disappointed that channel names must start with a letter :(

Comment: @TimoCengiz I tend to think it's more reliable to create an official PFUser object just so you can always access it no matter what happens, but if the only important user data you're storing is a phone number, you could technically save the user's phone number to NSUserDefaults and add it to a new anonymous user's table. I guess it really just depends on whether you want the user to log in and whether there's any other data to save.

Comment: @TimoCengiz Personally, in my own code, I've circumvented the "must start with a letter issue" by just adding an "x" or some other constant to the beginning. I've updated my answer to account for that issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69261/discussion-between-timo-cengiz-and-lyndsey-scott).

Comment: i just checkout @LyndseyScott and i am so happy to know that you are a successful model / Actor and a great Developer. its a very rare to find a person with such a different skill sets. Really Awesome and congrats. https://reurl.in/MwCYK