# Is parse.com push service really reliable or am i doing something wrong?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, parse-platform, push-notification

ok so i have used parse.com features for lots of things like storing information for a user etc...

I decided to use parse.com push service and i am not really satisfied with the result this far. It was really easy to set up and so on but the pushes that i send does not always being "sent".

Is anybody else having this problem and solved it?

Problem: I am running my application and pushing a button to send a push notification to myself. I wait around 30secs and then push the button again. Sometimes the notification reaches sometimes it does not. Here is an image of how it looks like.

[image]

These are all examples of tries i did when the application was running. sometimes it worked sometimes it does not as you see 1 meaning i received the push and i saw the alert and 0 nothing happened.
**EDIT**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
// Override point for customization after application launch.

[Parse setApplicationId:@""
              clientKey:@""];

// Register for Push Notitications
if ([application respondsToSelector: @selector (registerUserNotificationSettings :)]) {
    /*UIUserNotificationSettings * settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes: UIUserNotificationTypeBadge | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeSound categories: nil ];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings: settings];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
     */
    // Register for Push Notitications
    UIUserNotificationType userNotificationTypes = (UIUserNotificationTypeAlert |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeBadge |
                                                    UIUserNotificationTypeSound);
    UIUserNotificationSettings *settings = [UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:userNotificationTypes
                                                                             categories:nil];
    [application registerUserNotificationSettings:settings];
    [application registerForRemoteNotifications];
}
else {
    //using this code or else it crashes when device is using < IOS 8
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert |
     UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound];
}


return YES;
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken {
// Store the deviceToken in the current installation and save it to Parse.
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation setDeviceTokenFromData:deviceToken];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
}

- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"PushNotificationMessageReceivedNotification" object:nil userInfo:userInfo];

    [PFPush handlePush:userInfo];
}
```

**EDIT2** The "push" code

I do not really think it matters how the push code looks like since i tried to test this a couple of ways...

1) https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?app_id=pickmeup--15#parse_push/ios/existing
I used this code which is parses own code to send a push notification, same here it sometimes came, sometimes does not..

2) I used a provided curl push notification from parse.com, same result.

3) i used my own code where i press a button and send a push notification. here is the code

**The Cloud Code**

```
Parse.Cloud.define("sendPushToDevice", function(request, response) {
var message = "Please work!";
var friendChannel = "x" + request.params.number;
Parse.Push.send({
channels: [ friendChannel ],
data: {
    alert: message
}
}, {
success: function() {
    response.success("It worked");
},
error: function(error) {
    response.error("It failed");
}
});
});
```

**Objective-C code**

```
    NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:self.textField.text forKey:@"number"];

[PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendPushToDevice" withParameters:params block:^(id object, NSError *error) {
    if (!error) {
        NSLog(@"Success push sent");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Failed to push");
    }

}];
```

i always get the success push sent... but no push some times is arrived as mentioned earlier... hope you see a problem. Note i tried on foreground and background

**EDIT 3**

In the same ViewController as the push is sending i have set this up to receive push notifications.. Maybe this is the culprit?

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(remoteNotificationReceived:) name:@"PushNotificationMessageReceivedNotification"
                                           object:nil];
}




- (void)remoteNotificationReceived:(NSNotification *)notification
{


UIAlertView * alert =[[UIAlertView alloc ] initWithTitle:@"Test"
                                                 message:@"It worked"
                                                delegate:self
                                       cancelButtonTitle:@"Decline"
                                       otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert addButtonWithTitle:@"Accept"];
[alert show];
}
```

**EDIT 4**

Ok so i tried using this link again to try to send pushes. https://www.parse.com/apps/quickstart?app_id=pickmeup--15#parse_push/ios/existing

I also tried to send pushes via my own parse push panel and this time everything seems to be going smooth and working and the push notifications are reaching every time.

However now the problem still remains when i send a push using my own code the push notification reaches sometimes.

Still it is weird that it suddenly starts working.

So the last problem is my own sent push notification.

**EDIT5**

I subscribe to a channel in a view controller before this one. After clicking on next button i check if a verification code matches and if it is valid then i save it before i push to this view controller.

```
    NSString *xNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"%@%@", x, number];
    PFInstallation *currentInstallation = [PFInstallation currentInstallation];
    [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:xNumber forKey:@"channels"];
    [currentInstallation saveInBackground];
```

Comment: I have the same problem. I hope somebody has a solution for this i really need it to be 100% working pushes or else clients may be disappointed..

Comment: Yeah, I might have an answer actually... What *exactly* are you trying to send? Like what data,  etc.

Comment: And also could you post your Parse related code from the app delegate. I could think of two possible issues that could cause your notifications to be unreliable.

Comment: Edited my answer with the code from appdelegate. For starters i am simply sending a push notification with an alert: @"message" @LyndseyScott

Comment: Please show the code where you actually *send* the push.

Comment: I asked before but exactly what data are you trying to send? Posting the code Paulw11 mentioned would help...

Comment: @LyndseyScott I edited my question, sorry it took a while was sleeping..

Comment: Another edit, have a feeling edit 3 is the culprit @LyndseyScott

Comment: So are you always pushing to the same channel?

Comment: Yes these most recent tries were through the same channel but as i said in point 1 and 2 they did not use any channels, they sent to "all devices" which is currently just one @Paulw11

Comment: check the edit once again.. @Paulw11

Comment: Where are you subscribing to the channel?

Comment: Check edit 5 @LyndseyScott

Comment: X should be a string but you've written it as a variable

Comment: Bit i defined it before this code like this? is it still not a string? NSString *x = @"x";  @LyndseyScott

Comment: I changed the line of code to this and tried to send 6 pushes and every push reached ^^, Is it not counted as string if i did the way i did? Btw the line of code i changed to was the one you provided in my previous question: [currentInstallation addUniqueObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"x%@", number] forKey:@"channels"];