# The verification Procedure and making new users logic, parse.com

Tags: ios, objective-c, authentication, parse-platform, verification

I am stuck at how to think when to create new anonymous users. This is how my application is setup right now.

I got three ViewControllers.

1) **GetPhoneController**, 2) **VerificationController**
, 3) **ViewController**

**GetPhoneController:** is the first view where, IF the user that opened the application has no user stored meaning `[PFUser currentUser];` is equal to NULL then this view will be run otherwise **ViewController** will execute ( the check is done in AppDelegate ). This view will just get the user's phone number in a UITextField and is sent to the next controller

**VerificationController:** When this view is opened a text message is sent to the user with a VerificationCode. I am using Twilio with parse. The verification code is saved in a custom field in the User object to be used later for matching the codes.( problem here u will know why later).

A check is done if the user enters the right verification code, and if the user did do that THEN i want the anonymous user to be created and move on to the next controller. Why? Cause if i create a user before he is validated then in a scenario a user might shut the application down and then a user has been created for nothing taking up extra space.

**So my problem** is that i try to save the verification code to a user that does not exist since i want to create it AFTER validation.

A solution for this would be awesome or even better if you have a better solution to how to make the verification logic steps better.

Also i never sign out the user since i don't want the user to login after the verification is done, also it would mean that the anonymous user would be deleted, is that bad or is that ok to use like that?

Thank you!

Comment: why don't you just use one VC but just disable/enable buttons or sections as the information flow continues, that way if they do cancel your not creating any data in the backend ooorrrrr just don't create any users at all until the last VC

Comment: That would not help because the verification code is created in Cloud-Code and saved to the user field as the text verification code is created and sent to the user as text-message. I still want to create the user after validation happened which cant be done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to create a user in Parse before the validation is complete, you could save the validation token to `NSUserDefaults`.

In the method in VerificationController that sends the verification code...

```
NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
[defaults setObject:verificationCode forKey:@"code"];
[defaults synchronize];
```

Then, to check when the user enters the code, and taps a button...

```
- (void)userTappedCheckCodeButton:(id)sender {
  NSString *enteredCode = codeField.text;
  NSString *storedCode = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"code"];
  if ([enteredCode isEqualToString:storedCode]) {
    // Code matches. Create your anonymous user as the code has been verified.
  } else {
    // No code match. Tell the user, or maybe ask if they want to send the code again.
  }
}
```

--- Edit with new info that code generation happens server side ---

If you really don't want to create a User until they're verified and code generation happens server side, you could use create a new `VerificationToken` object in Parse. You can generate an identifier for the users device via `[[NSUUID UUID] UUIDString]`, and store in in `NSUserDefaults` (that way, you don't need to use the advertising identifier, and it's persistent across application executions). Send in that UUID with the request to generate and send the code to the user, and save it in the verification object with your cloud code function.

On the `VerificationController`, just send in the code with the UUID that you've retrieved from `NSUserDefaults`, search for the `VerificationToken` object that matches that, return success, and create the anonymous user.

And finally, if you're worried about having thousands of uncompleted `VerificationToken` objects cluttering up Parse, just tell users they only last for 24 hours, and create a scheduled cloud code job to go and delete all `VerificationToken` objects that have a `createdAt` date older than 1 day ago, and schedule the task to run daily.

Comment: I was not maybe clear but the verification code is sent by the cloud code and saved to the users field in the server. So a user needs to exist before saving it.

Comment: I dont understand where i am going to save the VerificationToken when there is no user to save it to?.  Can you elaborate a little more regarding that and the part where im going to generate an identifier for the users device.  THank you! @rickerbh

Comment: You don't need to save it against a user - it's saved as it's own object in Parse. When the user comes back to verify, the system will search for the VerificationToken that has the code the user has entered, as well as the UUID that was generated previously (the device will need to send both to Parse to match against). If you find a token with both the UUID and the code, then create your anonymous user. Else, reject the request.

Comment: is there any docs in parse.com that says how to do this or how it works? I have not seen any example of saving an object just like that @rickerbh

Comment: The [very first example in the Saving Objects section](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios_guide#objects-saving/iOS) in the documentation does exactly this. Saves an object without a user.